# Cisco ASA rekeying

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Good day

I was hoping someone has seen this before, I have a ASA5520 that has a l2l tunnel to a Palo Alto firewall. Every 2 mins the the logs I see a rekey I have check our configuration and we have everything exactly the same. I did find in my crypto map that for the ikev2 proposal I am pointing to the wrong one, it is slightly different in that the one that it is currently pointing to has the integrity as sha-1 md5  but it should be pointing to the one that only has sha-1.  I am hoping that that is the cause of the rekeying but just in case anyone ever seen this before?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can you please share lifetime settings on both ends?

Comment: crypto ikev2 policy 50
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 28800

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so we have fixed the issue, so for anyone having this similar issue where your tunnel rekeys every 2 mins.  Here is the situation your ASA version is PRE-9.7 and
in my case I am connecting to a Palo Alto.  On the Palo Alto side they will need to, on the IPSEC tunnel enable "PROXY ID" that will fix the rekeying issue